# How to paginate records while editing them?

Tags: mysql, pagination

I've got a mysql table of widgets.  The widget table has about 80,000 rows and 100 columns.

My client has an index page where they can see a list of widgets. They can filter and sort the list arbitrarily.  Pagination on the list works fine.

When a widget needs to have its data edited, user clicks the row and is taken to a widget edit page, which includes buttons to go to previous and next widget according to their arbitrary list.

The previous / next buttons work fine about half the time.

However, when client edits the widget record in such a way that the record no longer matches the original mysql query that created the list, the next button skips the widget that should have been next.

My solution for now is to save the indices of 1000 widgets, sorted by
the query (and centered around the selected widget).  This works until
the client clicks next as few as 500 times, they will have no "next"
record even though the original list said there were more.

I've tried saving indices of *all* the widgets, but it takes too long
in case the list includes all 80,000 widgets.

Is there a name for this problem?  If not, how about "paginedit"?
"mysql paginedit" currently has no hits on Google.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but it seems that the backend code of your system is creating a new record for the edited widget instead of updating it. If this is happening a new ID is created and the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses of the query will change the result. I'd focus on checking/changing the logic of the backend as a pure mysql solution is probably not viable in this case.

Comment: You are thinking along the right lines, but I've confirmed the backend is properly editing, and not creating new records.  "MySQL isn't the right tool" may be the key to how I can solve this.  Let's see!